# if the reduced row echelon form of a matrix [A, b] has a zero row, then the equation Ax=b has infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra

If any matrix in reduced row-echelon form has a zero row, wouldn't that mean that it has a free variable which would mean that it has infinitely many solutions?( The answer in the text says F)

Comment: What is "F"? I think I dont understand your question.

Comment: oh i meant the answer in the text is False

Comment: Don't just make the clarification in a comment. Edit your question to improve it.

Comment: @jjagmath sorry, this is my initial post, never used this before.

Answer (score 1):

It may have no solution. Try solving
$$
\pmatrix{0 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \cr}\pmatrix{x \cr y\cr} = \pmatrix{0 \cr 1}
$$

Comment: The OP used the augmented matrix [A, b]. Your counterexample doesn't work because the augmented matrix doesn't have a zero row.

Comment: @jjagmath Indeed, let me put another row of zeros.